# Erro no comando react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando criar um app com react-native, ja configurei o SDK do Android, o node e o react-native-cli. Mas quando eu rodo um react-native run-android, com um emulador aberto e tudo mais, ele da o seguine erro:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up
```

Já tentei re-instalar varias vezes o SDK, mas ate agr nada, ta adicionado as variaveis de ambiente o ANDROID_HOME com o caminho certo e no Path o %ANDROID_HOME%\tools e %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Alguém sabe oque pode ser?

Comment: Boa noite jovem, a RocketSeat tem uma doc bem interessante sobre o ambiente de desenvolvimento com react native. Vale dar uma conferida se não faltou algo. https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/windows

Answer (score 0):

Foi instalado a JDE também? Siga o passos de configuração do ambiente de desenvolvimento da rocketseat como já mencionado...
Porém aconselho que não utilize o react-native-cli, era uma solução para auxiliar a execução de script junto ao npm. Considerando que agora o npm tem seu executor de scrips direto dos repositórios, eu particularmente o utilizo, tendo o npm instalado só acrescentar npx antes dos comandos conhecidos do react-native-cli.
Exemplos.:

```
npx react-native run-android

npx react-native start
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, utilize esse passo a passo para instalação do ambiente de desenvolvimento em sua máquina:

https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/introducao